# How to connect using MODBUS RS485 to a slave to an address which also requests a password

Tags: connection, modbus, pymodbus

I tried to use different libraries : minimalmodbus, pymodbus, ... and find a way to connect to a device (power meter) which also requests a password.

Has anyone done such connection. I'm using serial connection of a Raspberry.

Thanks in advance for sharing your experience or ideas.

Comment: Please provide device model & manual/documentation.

Comment: The model is : MTR5LMOD from Polier. The link to the document is there : http://www.polier.fr/medias/files/mtr5lmod-compteur-electrique-polier.pdf  for general information. And the documentation for the ModBus is : http://www.polier.fr/medias/files/mtr5lmod-table-modbus-1.xlsx

Comment: From the document it looks like you need to send the password (using command 16 - write multiple holding registers) and then follow this up with a write command within 3 seconds. It looks like you should be able to read from the device without the password?

Comment: Hi ! Great ! Thanks Brits ! I will use also this for commands which need the password.
As far as reading is concerned, the problem was not the password, as you said, I'm able to read it without the password. The issue was : the slave address to be sent should be in decimal not hexadecimal, as said in the document.